# Python tkinter - auto indent a line in Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I am trying to make a `tk.Text` or `ttk.Text` widget..

In which when you hit `<TAB>`, it gives indent...

after that..

from the next line onwards, untill the tab is deleted it will indent lines

example:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a general-purpose auto-indenter that uses any indentation used by the current line including tabs and spaces, you can get the whitespace on the line, insert a newline, and then insert the same whitespace. Do this by binding to the `<Return>` event.

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

def auto_indent(event):
    text = event.widget

    # get leading whitespace from current line
    line = text.get("insert linestart", "insert")
    match = re.match(r'^(\s+)', line)
    whitespace = match.group(0) if match else ""

    # insert the newline and the whitespace
    text.insert("insert", f"\n{whitespace}")

    # return "break" to inhibit default insertion of newline
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

text.bind("<Return>", auto_indent)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is typo.  Either change `line` to `prev_line` or vice versa.

Comment: @acw1668: thanks for catching that. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of leading tabs `"\t"` then insert the same number of tabs in the next line.

Here is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def autoIndent():

    index = f"{text.index('insert')}-1l linestart"
    string = text.get(index, f"{index} lineend")
    
    tab_count = len(string)-len(string.lstrip("\t"))
    text.insert("insert linestart", "\t"*tab_count)

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.bind("<Return>", lambda ev:text.after(1, autoIndent))

text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your answer too was good but @Brian Oakley's answer was quite a bit simple...